# VUE.JS render function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, components

I´m studiying Vue.js and got stuck when using the bellow render function:

This is an javascript file that I called from my component.

```
import Button from './Button'

export default {
  functional: true,
    render(h) {
    return(
        <div id='toolbar'>
        <Button type='markup' tag='strong'> B </Button>
        <Button type='markup' tag='em'> I </Button>
        <Button type='section' tag='h1'> H1 </Button>
        <Button type='section' tag='h2'> H2 </Button>
        <Button type='section' tag='ul'> UL </Button>
        <Button type='section' tag='ol'> OL </Button>
        <slot />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I need to export the above function, but I´m getting error.

```
      5 |     render(h) {
      6 |     return(
   >  7 |         <div id='mobiledoc-toolbar'>
        |         ^
      8 |         <Button type='markup' tag='strong'> B </Button>
```

I´m getting error when calling this function, not sure if this only works using backqouts/backticks

Comment: Firstly I don't quite get the question. But to point you in the right direction use ES6 Template Strings to return the markup. Have a look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @bernIt it seems like you should provide a `Markup` library that you use.

Comment: @henk.io & GONG - I created a component called editor, this component imports javascript file with the render function above, the JS file imports button markups stuff all should be rendered in the component editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In redux, you can indeed mix HTML markup with JavaScript. But there's no such thing in Vue.js. The only way would be to wrap your HTML in template string:

```
return(`
    <div id='mobiledoc-toolbar'>
    ...
    </div>
`
```

or to use `<template>` template format for vue (if you're using webpack). Such components look like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="toolbar">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default new Vue(

    );
</script>

<style lang="scss">
  // Your styles here
</style>
```

and then no `render()` method is necessary.

PS: Yes, as @Bert suggested, you can also use Babel [JSX Transform plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx) and use JSX syntax.

Comment: So my issues is based on my lack of understanding how vue works, because I thought that maybe I could mix HTML markup with JavaScript in vue. The information posted help me understand the basics on vueJS, thanks for the tips